What motivated Democritus to discover the volume of a cone?
In the works of Archimedes, it is mentioned that Democritus was the first to discover that the volume of a cone is 1/3 that of the cylinder with the same base and same height.
I am curious to know about what motivated Democritus to discover this.
Other than intellectual curiosity, which is a somewhat unsatisfying answer, was there some operational motivation, i.e. in Greek astronomy or mechanics?
I can't think of why someone in Greek times was trying to find the volume of a cone, other than as an intermediate step to calculate the volume of a sphere maybe as Archimedes did, or for some mechanical/architectural reasons which the Greeks had that I am unaware of.
Any known theories or sources?

Well, I guess he tried how many cones have the same volume as a cylindre with the same size. Probably he used the Archimedian principle to measure the volumes.

Hi Peter - It doesn't really explain his motivation..why would he be investigating the problem in the first place?

This question might be a better for for HSM, but ancient Egyptians needed the analogous result for square-based pyramids in architecture, so if Democritus had a practical motive it might be that.

Well , what motivates someone do do experiments ? Simply Curiosity.

I can't make any definitive statements about the historical motivation, but I think this is a pretty natural question. For example suppose you dig a large cone-shaped hole in the ground, and you'd like to fill it with water. How much water is that? Or: suppose you want to estimate the volume of a mountain, which is roughly cone-shaped. How big is that?

Democritus was one of the earliest "Atomists" who though that all large things (even mathematical things) could be built up by the most elementary things.
While thinking about the Paradoxes of Zeno & other related things (tiniest matter , tiniest time interval , tiniest length) , Democritus considered the thinnest layers of various Solids , which were termed laminae.
These laminae could be put together to get back the Solid.
Now there was some Contradiction there :
Will the laminae of Cylinder match the laminae of Cone ?
If YES , then how can the Cone differ from Cylinder ?
If NO , then how can the "atomic" laminae differ ?
Paradox !
We need not go into the resolution there , except to take it that the laminae for Cone should be "jagged" when stacked up , whereas the Cylinder will have a "smooth" stack.
Those "Atomism" Concepts were the motivations for Democritus.
Motivation was most likely not some Engineering Activity or Mathematical theorem. Proof of that "formula" was not a concern for Democritus ( Proof was eventually given by Eudoxus )
[[ I am interpolating on what concepts/ideas/thoughts Democritus had & what texts are currently known & what later writers wrote. That is a reasonable approach , given that there is nothing else available , mostly getting lost in the mists of time ]]

Did some more research, and this is what my theory is,starting from the principle: mathematical invention fundamentally comes from a computational need (which for the Egyptians/Babylonians was certainly true, i believe the same applies to the Greeks) then you have to consider why the area of a cone was being considered in the first place by Democritus.  I believe that a cone was a shape usful for a water clock, where it was important/required to know the area of a cone, see a clepsydra (which was conical), leading to his computation and then the Paradoxes of Zeno coming after.

The physical fact of equal volumina for different shapes, cylinder and cuboid as a gauge, is known to the Babylonians.
The discussion of the equality of becomes critical with the invention of coins and overseas trade in oil, wine etc during the 6th century BC. By the new economy this question became a topic at courts with 1000 methods of cheating.
Even the fact, that the volume is the same independent of its content was a topic  of mathematical discussions. Democrit made the important statement that the empty container has the same volume as the full. It's a giant step in philosophy and geometry, to postulate that the empty space  has metric  properties.
Its an old topic,  discussion going back to Plutarchos, one of the few sources about Democritus.
REINHARD SEIDE: On the problem of geometric atomism in Democritus
Translation thanks to google:
p. 8

As Plutarch tells us (Chapter 39, Moralia 1079 EF), the Stoic
Chrysippus believed that with this theory he could solve the dilemma
that Democritus had encountered in his stereometric work. According to
him, the Abderite was not able to state whether the surfaces that
result from the intersection of a right circular cone with planes
parallel to its base are equal or unequal; because none of the
alternatives preserves the integral shape of the cone. In the case of
inequality, the cone's mantle has steps and is therefore not smooth,
while in the case of equality, a cylinder results26.
This passage has already been discussed many times, without the
factual and historical context being taken into account in every case
(see Appendix II). When Otto TOEPLITZ remarks in his lecture on the
genesis of infinitesimal calculus on the occasion of the determination
of the volume of a cone by Democritus that “from the many things that
have been printed on the subject” it is still not clear what
Democritus’ method really looked like, then one must say that this
situation has not changed to this day.

